# Инициализация UIStackView в UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, swift3

```
class TableViewCellStack: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var stack: UIStackView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

 init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?,label: UILabel?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.stack.addArrangedSubview(label!)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

}
```

Ошибка в self.stack.addArrangedSubview(label!) :

```
  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Как сделать так чтобы стеквью успевала инициализироваться в конструкторе?
Если добавлять сабвью в tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) то при реюзе они дублироваться будут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь несколько ошибок:

1. в методе `init(style:reuseIdentifier:label:)` атрибут `label` опциональный, соответственно перед тем как добавлять его в subview, хорошо бы его проверить на nil
2. IBOutlet не всегда, инициализируется вместе с инициализацией самого view, поэтому `stack` также может быть nil в `init(style:reuseIdentifier:label:)`. Outlet'ы можно использовать только после метода `awaikeFromNib', который как раз таки создает их nib, либо из storyboard и привязывает с самим view.
3. Возможно здесь путаница с атрибутом `label`. Я не совсем понял почему он используется как аутлет и тут-же передается в инициализатор в качестве параметра.

Поэтому вижу здесь такое решение:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCellStack: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stack: UIStackView!

    fileprivate var labelFromInit: UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        guard let labelFromInit = labelFromInit else { return }
        self.stack.addArrangedSubview(labelFromInit)
    }

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?, label: UILabel?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        labelFromInit = label
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Также всегда с опциональными переменными необходимо использовать конструкцию `guard let else` для безопасного 'разворачивания'.